# I renamed my css file and now it doesn't work

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Doing a website for a client and I merely changed the name of the css file in the folder and in the references on each page. And suddenly all my styling is gone. I've checked multiple times for spelling errors and it's all correct and I do believe I have referenced it correctly as it was working previously under a different name. My Question is How can the changing of the css file suddenly stop it working if it's still referenced correctly? Could it be that bootstrap is overriding it somehow?

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--Reference Bootstraop.min before plugins.js but after jquery.js. We alterbootstrap javascript with plugins.js -->
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is the `<head>` for my index html file.

The problem only occurred when I changed the file names but I can't leave it as "TestLayout" when it is a completed project. Any help is appreciated and I can supply what I can to help find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a full refresh (ctrl + F5) or emptying your browser cache?

Comment: Are you able to open css file by following link given in source code?

Comment: Check your Network tab to find errors related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First off, a small tip:** Load your custom CSS-file AFTER the `bootstrap.css` file. This way you can ensure that your styles are easily overriding the defaults of Bootstrap, so you don't have to bash in `!important` in order to change something.

And for your question, have you accidentally removed `css/` from the beginning of your `style.css`? Since all the other CSS styles you have linked are under the CSS-folder.

Double check that, otherwise it should work, the name is valid.

Comment: Yeah I moved the custom down and you were right, I had forgotten to reference the css folder in my path. Silly mistakes! Thanks for spotting it :)

Comment: Happens. Glad to help, keep on coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the path to your CSS file is still correct (and you haven't inadvertently removed the folder from the file path as per ProDexorite's answer) then you might need to completely refresh your browser.

You can do this with CTRL+F5 or to be completely sure you can empty your browser cache, although I usually find this isn't necessary.

ProDexorite is also correct regarding the CSS files - it's called Cascading Style Script which means any styles in the files you load last will overwrite the files loaded before. Therefore any custom CSS (main.css and style.css for example) should be loaded AFTER the Bootstrap or any other library css files. This just means you need to reference them in the right order in your page that's all.